# Show that if $X,Y$ are topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$ is a continous function , then $f$ is a Borel measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

Show that if $X,Y$ are topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$ is a continous function , then $f$ is a Borel measurable.

Any help what am I supposed to prove here ?

My attempt:

$\mathcal{B}(X) $ is the open subsets of $X$ , $\mathcal{B}(Y)$ is the open subsets of $Y$.

I want to prove that $f^{-1}(U) \in\mathcal{B}(X)$ where $U\in \mathcal{B}(Y) $

$f$ is a continous function implies that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open $\forall $ open $U\subset Y$.

Hence $f^{-1}(U) \in\mathcal{B}(X)$  $\forall U\in \mathcal{B}(Y) $ .

$f$ is borel-measure.

Is my proof correct ?

Comment: You are using the fact that it is enough to look at generators of   sigma-algebra on Y.

Comment: $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is not the collection of open set, this is the sigma algebra on $X$ generated by the open sets. (i.e the smallest sigma algebra which contains all the open sets of $X$) In general, it is much larger than just the collection of open sets. So if you assumed an open set in $Y$ is a general element of $\mathcal{B}(Y)$ then the proof is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the definitions of your concepts more clearly.  *Outline:*

Let $\mathcal{O}(X)$ be the open sets of $X$, let $\mathcal{O}(Y)$ be the open sets of $Y$.  Then let $\mathcal{B}(X)$ be the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ generated by $\mathcal{O}(X)$, let $\mathcal{B}(Y)$ be the $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$ generated by $\mathcal{O}(Y)$.

*We assume* (a) $f : X \to Y$ is **continuous**, that is: for every $U \in \mathcal{O}(Y)$ we have $f^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal{O}(X)$.

*We want to show* (b) for every $E \in \mathcal{B}(Y)$ we have $f^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal{B}(X)$.

Do this in steps.
(c) for every $U \in \mathcal{O}(Y)$ we have $f^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal{B}(X)$.  [From (a) and definition of $\mathcal{B}(X)$]

Let
$$
\mathcal{F} = \big\{E \subseteq Y : f^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal{B}(X)\big\}
$$
Show (d.1) $\mathcal{F} \supseteq \mathcal{O}(Y)$  [From (c)]
(d.2) $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra  [Use properties of $f^{-1}$; this is the heart of the proof.]
Deduce (d) $\mathcal{F} \supseteq \mathcal{B}(Y)$.  [From (d.1) and (d.2) and definition of $\mathcal{B}(Y)$.]
Conclude (b).